# Multi-relationship query neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to find out what publications have collaborated with a university.

I am new to neo4j, I'm not sure how to exactly go about it. I tried the query below, but this only returns records that are within that university only. I need to pull other universities that have collaborated.

This is what I have tried:

```
MATCH (f:FACULTY)-[p:PUBLISH]->(P:PUBLICATION),(f)<-[a:AFFILIATION_WITH]-(i:INSTITUION)
WHERE i.name = "UNIVERSITY_NAME"
RETURN i.name;
```

Also here is a description of the graph:
[image]

Comment: Please provide example data and wanted results, so We'll be able to help. An example data: MERGE (mark:Person:DevRel {name: "Mark"})
MERGE (lju:Person:DevRel {name: "Lju"})
MERGE (praveena:Person:Engineering {name: "Praveena"})
MERGE (zhen:Person:Engineering {name: "Zhen"}) MERGE (zhen)-[:KNOWS]-(praveena)
MERGE (zhen)-[:KNOWS]-(lju) - this fills a neo4j db

Comment: please give us example output/result that you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you're almost there:

```
MATCH (i:INSTITUTION)<-[:AFFILIATION_WITH]-(:FACULTY)-[:PUBLISH]->(p:PUBLICATION)
WHERE i.name = "UNIVERSITY_NAME"
RETURN p.name;
```

Here, I am traversing the graph from an institution (university) down to the publication, through the faculty, and returning the name of the publication.

A couple of notes compared to your initial try:

1. The **direction** of the relationship Institution -> Faculty in your query does not match the one on your graph
2. You want to return publication names, not institutions